# How to get the url name from a django url path?

Tags: python-3.x, django, path, django-urls

In my view i export the main_url_patterns from my app and i want to process this list to get two parts in a different lists:

1. URL path
2. URL name

So in my view i do something like that:

```
def siteurls_view(request):

    path_list=urls.main_urlpatterns

    url_list=[]

    for p in path_list:
        print(p, type(p),p[0])
```

Where urls.main_urlpatterns is:

```
path('consumptions_points/send/', views.send_consumptions_points_view, name='send_consumptions_points'),
    path('consumptions/', views.consumptions_view, name='consumptions'),
    path('consumptions/new/', views.consumptions_new_view, name='consumptions_new'),
    path('consumptions/get_tx/', views.get_tx_consumption_view, name='get_tx_consumption'),
    path('consumptions/send/', views.send_consumptions_view, name='send_consumptions')
```

So i would like to get for example all names from the path and insert them into a new list.

urls.main_urls_patterns is type of: <class 'django.urls.resolvers.URLPattern'>

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a script made by @Cesar Canassa and it goes like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import URLPattern, URLResolver

urlconf = __import__(settings.ROOT_URLCONF, {}, {}, [''])

def list_urls(lis, acc=None):
    if acc is None:
        acc = []
    if not lis:
        return
    l = lis[0]
    if isinstance(l, URLPattern):
        yield acc + [str(l.pattern)]
    elif isinstance(l, URLResolver):
        yield from list_urls(l.url_patterns, acc + [str(l.pattern)])
    yield from list_urls(lis[1:], acc)

for p in list_urls(urlconf.urlpatterns):
    print(''.join(p))
```

This code prints all URLs, unlike some other solutions it will print the full path and not only the last node. In case you want to add `names` you change

```
yield acc + [str(l.pattern)]
print(''.join(p))
```

with:

```
yield acc + [str(l.pattern)], l.callback
print(''.join(p[0]))
```

but keep in mind that this prints out the view's function name and not a `name`